# full implementation of b+ tree

Tags: java

I am looking for an implementation of b+ tree in java. Does anyone know where I can find the proper and full implementation? When I say proper - I mean that each inner node must have at least N/2 to N children and each leaf must have between M/2 to M records. 
I have the following link http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Transwi...tation_In_Java but it is not enough. I dont think the code takes into account that the tree has to be constantly balanced and that each inner node must have more than N/2 children. I dont know how to add that to the code. 
Any suggestions???

Thank you

Comment: you should ask for the hint not the whole code exactly as your requirement you have to get hint and implement it as per your requirements..you can refer http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2004/cmsc420/sp04-part2v03/node28.html just for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [full implementation of b+ tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518895/full-implementation-of-b-tree)

Comment: @EJP The one you've linked appears to be the later instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recall [JDBM](https://github.com/jankotek/JDBM3) . Take a look , might helpful for you .

Answer (score 0):

There is also the MapDB on github: http://www.mapdb.org/.